# Ng-class dosen't work as i expected with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

here is my code HTML:

```
<div ng-click="changeBorder(value)" ng-class="{active_borders:isActive(value)}" ng-repeat="value in values">
            <img class="card-img-bottom" src="{{value.Imagen}}" />
        </div>
```

Here is my code javascript:

```
$scope.isActive = function isActive(value){return $scope.valueSelected.Id==value.Id;}

$scope.changeValue=function changeValue(value){$scope.valueSelected=value;}
```

EXPLANATION:
What i'm traying to do is when i click the div which contains a img so when i'm traying to select a image, i want to paint the border of that div, only that one. So if i click in one div and after in other the only div it should be painted it should be the last one i clicked.

MY PROBLEM:
The problem is that the function isActive(value) is being run two times when it should be run one time that is when is running the ng-repeat if i'm write.

I don't want to be run two times because i'm going to add extra things in that method that are going to communicate with my database and it will be a problem if it is constantly communicating to the database.

Comment: _"when i click"_... if you want something done when you click then put the code there. Why would you put it in the `isActive()` call?

Comment: Imagine that you are showing 5 photos, each photo has some properties and i want to disable those photos which doesn't have certain property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind `isActive` evaluating twice is, whenever Angular fires digest cycle it evaluates all the bindings of your page, to keep your page in sync with models that are bounded to it. This is normal behaviour in AngularJS application. Also if you think in performance perspective, it will not hurt performance in any manner as its `$scope.valueSelected.Id==value.Id;`(equality check) of two variables.

Currently `isActive` function is running twice or it could run more number of times than that(depends on digest cycle run), it totally depends what application is doing.

> I don't want to be run two times because i'm going to add extra things
>   in that method that are going to communicate with my database and it
>   will be a problem if it is constantly communicating to the database.

Big NO for what you're thinking, its bad practice to put API/`network call` inside `binding` function. It you go for it, then that function will keep on calling infinite time, and digest cycle will never stable.

Rather I'd recommend you to keep your DB call inside `$scope.changeValue` method which will get call only when user performs some action. This make sense much, as we are doing what application should intended to do in architecture point of view.

Comment: What you said about infinite calls it happend to me in other isActive function. I removed it. Thanks you. I'm going to re-think what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Angular will frequently run functions in scope multiple times when something changes until everything "settles down". This is necessary because of dependencies which may cause a change in one scope variable to affect another. If this behaviour is a problem, you'll need to think about a different approach, because you can't stop it happening. `IsActive` should really do only one thing: return whether the object is active. It should not make API calls. Consider what it is you're trying to achieve and re-architect your controller to avoid multiple calls.

EDIT: I should clarify: it *is* possible under some circumstances to prevent multiple calls, but relying on there only being one call is a mistake and the approach of having API calls inside what is a really like a "GET (a read method)" is the wrong way to go.

Comment: Thank you very much for de explanation and the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

try this, make sure default value of `$scope.valueSelected = {}` otherwise it'll throw an error, can't read property id of undefined.

```
<div ng-click="changeBorder(value)" ng-class="{'active_borders':valueSelected.Id==value.Id}" ng-repeat="value in values">
    <img class="card-img-bottom" src="{{value.Imagen}}" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks men, i did this and approach the part of API calls different.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you many need like below. id="{{value.id}}"

```
<div id="{{value.id}}" ng-click="changeBorder(value)" ng-class="{active_borders:isActive(value)}" ng-repeat="value in values">
            <img class="card-img-bottom" src="{{value.Imagen}}" />
        </div>
```

Comment: You are saying to add an id, and that fix my problem of 2 calls to my function isActive(value)?